# haskell list and functional

Tags: list, sorting, haskell

This is homework that has been driving crazy for the last couple of days.

I got a list that I am applying a function to - pushing each element to the right if the element next to it is smaller then the previous one.

My function to pass over the list once and sort the head of the list:

```
sortEm lis@(x:y:xs) = if x > y then y: sortEm (x:xs) else lis
sortEm [x] = [x]
sortEm [] = []

myList (x:y:xs) = if x > y then sortEm lis else x:myList(y:xs)
myList [] = []
myList [x] = [x]
```

But my problem is that once that sortem has finished it returns either an empty list or a list containing one element, how would i design this the functional way?

I was thinking about foldl and some haskell magic to go along with that but currently I am stuck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you're just looking for code samples, try [Literate Programs](http://en.literateprograms.org/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=sort+haskell) or [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/mw/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=sort).

Comment: `sortEm [5,4,3,2,1]` results in `[4,3,2,1,5]` --- not an empty list or a single element list. Can you clarify what your problem is?

Comment: how would i apply sortEm to each element in the list? And thank you Daniel for the links, reading through some code, the Haskell syntax is beautiful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myList []       = []
myList (x : xs) = sortEm (x : myList xs)
```

(untested)

Or in terms of a fold:

```
myList = foldr cons []
  where cons x xs = sortEm (x : xs)
```

(also untested)

Comment: But one more thing how would i apply sortem only once to each element in the list so for example that [4,2,6,1,8] => [2,4,1,6,8]? Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

First of, your `sortEm` function name is misleading, it doesn't sort its argument list but *inserts* its head element into its tail. As it happens, there is an `insert` function already in [`Data.List` module](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html) that inserts its first argument into the 2nd, so there's an equivalency

```
sortEm (x:xs) === Data.List.insert x xs
```

Now, inserting an item will only get you a sorted list back if you're inserting it into a list that is already sorted. Since empty list is sorted, that's what `myList` function does that you got in dave4420's answer. That is an ["insertion" sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), progressively inserting elements of list into an auxiliary list, initially empty. And that's what the 2nd function does that you got in dave4420 answer:

```
insertionSort xs = foldr Data.List.insert [] xs
```

This does "apply sortem" i.e. inserts, "each element" only once. For a list `[a,b,c,...,z]` it's equivalent to

```
insert a (insert b (insert c (... (insert z []) ...)))
```

What you probably meant in your comment, i.e. comparing (and possibly swapping) two neighboring elements "only once", is known as [*bubble sort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). Of course making only one pass through the list won't get it sorted, in a general case:

```
bubbleOnce xs = foldr g [] xs  where
  g x [] = [x]
  g x xs@(y:ys) | x>y       = y:x:ys  -- swap x and y in the output
                | otherwise = x:xs    -- keep x before y in the output
```

Now, `bubbleOnce [4,2,6,1,8] ==> [1,4,2,6,8]`. The value that you expected, `[2,4,1,6,8]`, would result from applying the folding function `g` in an opposite direction, from the left to the right. <s>But that's much less natural to do here with Haskell lists:</s>

```
bubbleOnce' [] = []
bubbleOnce' (x:xs) = let (z,h)=foldl g (x,id) xs in (h [z])  where
  g (x,f) y | x>y       = (x, f.(y:))   -- swap x and y in the output
            | otherwise = (y, f.(x:))   -- keep x before y in the output
```

**(edit:)** see [jimmyt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10997158/849891) for the equivalent, but simple and nice version using straightforward recursion. It is also lazier (less strict) than both the `fodlr` and `foldl` versions here.

Answer (score 2):

```
-- if..then..else version
sortEM      ::  Ord a => [a] -> [a]

sortEM (x:y:xs)     =   if x < y
                        then x : sortEM (y:xs)
                        else y : sortEM (x:xs)
sortEM b            =   b   


-- guard version
sortEM_G    ::  Ord a => [a] -> [a]

sortEM_G (x:y:xs)
     | x < y        =   x : sortEM_G (y:xs)
     | otherwise    =   y : sortEM_G (x:xs)
sortEM_G b          =   b
```

Comment: your version is different from the OP version, yet it still won't *sort* its argument: `sortEM [4,2,6,1,8] ==> [2,4,1,6,8]`. But what it *is*, is a much simpler version of `bubbleOnce'` from my answer. Kudos for that. :) Except that you needlessly swap when `x == y` too; it's probably better to test for `x>y` and exchange the consequent and the alternative clauses. Also please note that it is customary here on SO to not give out full code for questions with "homework" tag. :) +1.